# My motherboard beeps when I launch something heavy on my PC

Tags: motherboard

https://youtu.be/CKVEx6FYxuk

Some time ago I noticed that my motherboard started to beep (as shown on video) when launching Ubuntu. I tested my GPUs (the one replacing them can be seen on video), RAM, HDD, but everything was working fine, then it turned out that it was because of FAH running on background and after disabling it everything seemed to work fine.

But later on, when playing GTA, or even less hungry games my motherboard beeps (not as long as on video, though) and I don't understand how to fix that, it's the first time something like that occured on my pc.

EDIT. I found out that it's actually speaker whining (the one on motherboard)

EDIT2. Here's video - https://youtu.be/2Tm0ahzCghM

EDIT3. I found out 2 things - BIOS starts beeping when CPU temp reaches ~81 degrees celsium and that my BIOS was outdated. And after updating it I started loading CPU and GPU again and now I don't hear any beeping sounds from motherboard speaker.

Thanks everyone for your answers.

Comment: This isn't a beep. That is a fan making noise (or maybe whine from a coil, but that is usually much higher in pitch). When the computer is under load it gets hotter and the fan needs to spin faster. It is rubbing on something or the fan-bearings are worn. Use a tube (or roll a sheet of paper into a tube) and use that as a hearing aid. One end to your ear and the other close to each fan. That should help identify which fan is causing it. CPU fan or Gfx card fan are the most likely candidates.

Comment: Check all your fans, because probably that's something hitting them, also check the PSU fan maybe the problem is right there.

Comment: I stress tested my CPU and GPU, firstly separately, then together and the strange thing is that beep occured only when I loaded either CPU and GPU at the same time, of course fans started spinning a way faster, than minute ago, but the beep sound nothing like them, it may be a coil whine, but I have no idea on how to test it, maybe you will suggest something?

Comment: It could be an alarm from the BIOS. You will have to go through its settings and see if an alarm is set for anything, e.g. undervoltage or over-temperature or fan failure.

Comment: I don't see anything like that in the BIOS settings